# Which Rabbi was this?

Tags: history, rabbis, historical-figures, jewish-american-history

I remember reading a journal article about a modern orthodox rabbi in late 19th century America who held the position that rabbis need to try to find lenient halachik rulings to make the lives of their congregants easy. As far as I recall the rabbi was based in Hoboken NJ or somewhere nearby there. Any idea which Rabbi this was?

Comment: Jewish Action quoted Rav Ovadya Yosef as holding this way as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fyi - I eventually dug up the answer on Google - [Rabbi Hayyim Hirschensohn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaim_Hirschensohn)

Comment: Smart man. Seems that there is a dramatic reversal trend toward that thinking today. I wonder if that's caused mainly by a thinking that the congregants are less studious and educated, today, or perhaps because many rabbis may not be as well educated to know the nuances of halachot that may be there?

Comment: I have always been taught this way in Halachah.